# Is the secondary winding (black wire) on these transformers in series or parallel configuration?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, transformer

Are these two microwave transformers (secondary output) in series or parallel configuration? Yes, the primary is in parallel but I would like to know about the secondary. This setup is for a lithium-ion cell spot welding application.

[image]

Comment: They appear to me to be in series. To have them in parallel would require a junction, that I do not see. Of course, it is always possible that what I do not see is merely obscured, but I don't think so in this case.

Comment: An [18650 spot welder](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313&_nkw=18650+spot+welder&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_odkw=spot+welder&_osacat=0) can be found which is much more practical than this behemoth.  Check reviews carefully of course.

Comment: Yeah I know but I already have 2 transformers, wire and the control. Another thing I am not inclined towards these cheap spot welders due to the fact that most spot welders need battery. I just don't want to maintain the battery. Just plug it into the outlet and start welding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from the photo, that the two secondaries of the microwave oven transformers are made from a single continuous wire. This would make the secondaries "in series". For the secondaries to be "in parallel" would require that there be a junction or "split" in the wires. There does not appear to be such a junction in the image, unless it is carefully concealed.

Note that in a sense, there is actually multiple secondary windings on each of the two transformers, and these windings are all in series, with the windings on one transformer alternating with the windings on the other transformer. It certainly wouldn't be wrong to treat the circuit as such.

Comment: Yes the secondary definitely looks like made from a single continuous wire. So the voltage will get  doubled and current will remain the same?

Comment: The voltage will be doubled (assuming everything is "ideal"). The actual current that flows may possibly change because the voltage is higher. However, the maximum _rated_ current will be unchanged (assuming everything is "ideal"). To clarify, If your load were a pure resistance, doubling the voltage will double the current through the load. If when the load is supplied by a single transformer, the transformer is at max current, then when the (resistive) load is supplied by two transformers in series, the actual current will double, and the transformers will be overloaded.